# How to install newest PulseAudio with all packages though terminal?

Tags: 16.04, pulseaudio

I can't pair my Ubuntu 16.10 to Creative Intuitive S2 speakers using bluetooth. I think my system needs additional PulseAudio packages.

How can I check my PulseAudio packages and update them if needed?

Comment: Why do you think you need to update PulseAudio?

Comment: Because, I don't even know my pulse audio version, and what packages i have.

Comment: Well, PulseAudio doesn't control Bluetooth pairing. Have you been able to pair other devices with your computer, and have you been able to pair your speakers to another computer?

Comment: I can pair my computer to my phone. So I need more advanced tool for my bluetooth, or just give up and go buy new speakers?

Comment: I would assume something is wrong with your Bluetooth drivers. I'd ask a new question asking why you can't pair Bluetooth devices to your computer, as that is out-of-scope for this question.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem *extremely* unlikely that you'd need to manually install *more* PulseAudio packages. The general rule with installing packages is that if you don't know why you need it, don't do it. This rule is even more important when you're trying to install packages for completely separate subsystems (installing audio packages to fix Bluetooth, for example).

However, updating your packages is pretty easy, and should be done regularly. Just pop open a terminal and run these two commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

This will upgrade all of your packages and programs to the latest versions known in the Ubuntu repositories and any additional PPAs that you may have manually added to your system.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do it by command :-
`sudo apt-get install pulseaudio*`

Comment: Installing just everything somehow related to a certain package or at least it's name doesn't seem to be a very clever solution to me...

Comment: upvoting because this solved my problem and the top answer didn't.